# Creating div's from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, append

So I am creating a platformer game with jQuery, JavaScript and HTML. I would like to make every level with an array containing numbers. Each number will then be a "block" of the platformer.

For instance:

```
var level = ["10101"];
```

Would create 3 different blocks, each of with are seperated by a blank space.

---

However, in the platformer, every number of the array caracterises the height, so a `2` would be on top of a `1`.

See where I'm going?

---

---

Thing is, I have no clue how to append a series of `div`'s to the game so that they have diffrent `x` position to fill the `.game` div.

Plus, I added a `for` loop with a variable named `j`, however, if I take out anything to do with `j`and the loop itself, the code doesn't work... why?

I have the code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/FlipFloop/pen/aBBYPz),  but here is what I have done so far anyway (for some reason it doesn't work on stackoverflow):

> **IMPORTANT**: The CodePen uses SCSS, not CSS, I converted the code using [SassMeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/) !

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var level = ["1112222111111111111"];

  for (var i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < level[i].length; j++) {
      var n = level[i][j];
      var s = $(".block").width();

      if (n === "1") {
        $("<div>", {
          "class": "block pos1" //or any other logic applied to your borad
        }).appendTo(".game");
        $(this).css("left", i * s + "px")
      }

      if (n === "2") {
        $("<div>", {
          "class": "block pos2" //or any other logic applied to your borad
        }).appendTo(".game");
      }
    }
  }





});
```

```css
.game {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc((100% - 800px)/2);
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.block {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 0.5px solid red;
}
.pos1 {
  bottom: 0;
}
.pos2 {
  bottom: 50px;
}
.pos3 {
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="game">

  <!-- examples of positions -->
  <!--<div class = "block pos1"></div>
 <div class = "block pos2"></div>
 <div class = "block pos5"></div>
 <div class = "block pos4"></div>-->

</div>
```

**Please Help!**

Thank you! Tell me if I need to be more clear!

Answer (score 1):

To append the element using [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2), replace

```
for(var each in level) {
    level[each].$(".game").append("<div class = 'block pos3'></div>");
}
```

with

```
for(var i = 0, length = level.length; i < length; i++){
    $("<div>", {
        "class": "block pos" + level[i] //or any other logic applied to your borad
    }).appendTo(".game");
}
```

Also, `for(var i in obj)` is for iterating through the properties of an object, the sequence of the element being iterated is not guaranteed. For arrays, you should use `for(var i = 0; i < x; i++)` [Javascript for loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

Comment: @FlipFloop sorry, missed the `$` in front of `("<div>")`. Also, i added the `jQuery` reference in your [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoNoxw)